# lost on regular expression

Tags: php, regex

First: Sorry for so basic question on regular expresions.

I have this expression:

```
AND CAST(wordpress_postmeta.meta_value AS CHAR) = 'g' )
)
```

And I Want that preg_replace change that into

```
AND CAST(wordpress_postmeta.meta_value AS CHAR) LIKE '%g%' )
)
```

This regular_expression is close, but not enough:

```
$where = preg_replace('/(\.meta_value[^=]*)=(.*)$/U', "$1 LIKE $2", $where);
```

How is the correct regular expression for this general case?

Comment: you want to find the expression, or recreate what the expression does in php? If so, you don't need a regex for a simple `like` clone. that'd basically be `strpos(...) !== false`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use:

```
$where = preg_replace("/(\\.meta_value[^=]*)=\\h*'([^']+)'/", "$1 LIKE '%$2%'", $where);
```

[RegEx Demo](https://regex101.com/r/sG5tA7/1)

Answer (score 0):

Try this one:
(.meta_value[^=]*)=*\s*\'\"[\'\"].*$